# Python Ctypes struct with bitfields has a different memory layout than the struct in C

Tags: python, c, ctypes, bit-fields

I have to concrete questions about **Ctypes** and the way they define structs. To give you a little bit of context, please consider the following example in C which defines a struct with **bitfields**:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Version
{
    uint8_t  n1;
    uint8_t  n2;
    uint32_t n3:16;
} vv;

int main(void)
{
    vv.n1 = 0xab;
    vv.n2 = 0xef;
    vv.n3 = 0x1234;

    uint8_t* ptr = (uint8_t*)(&vv);
    printf("size %u\n", sizeof(vv));
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(vv); ++i) printf("%2x ", ptr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

which seems to generate the same definition for both 32 and 64 architectures:

```sh
$ gcc sample.c -o a -m64 -std=gnu99 -w && ./a
size 4
ab ef 34 12
$ gcc sample.c -o a -m32 -std=gnu99 -w && ./a
size 4
ab ef 34 12
```

Everything is fine until there, but when I write the equivalent struct in python using *ctypes* I get a different definition:

```
from ctypes import *


class Version(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('n1', c_uint8, 8),
        ('n2', c_uint8, 8),
        ('n3', c_uint32, 16),
    ]


vv = Version()
vv.n1 = 0xab
vv.n2 = 0xef
vv.n3 = 0x1234

print('bytes', bytes(vv).hex())
print('size', sizeof(vv))
```

because the ctypes struct uses 5 bytes instead of 4 (which is the one chosen by C)

```
$ python sample.py
bytes abef341200
size 5
```

and if I change the type of `n3` in python from `c_uint32` to `c_uint16` it seems to have the same layout as the code written in C:

```
class Version(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('n1', c_uint8, 8),
        ('n2', c_uint8, 8),
        ('n3', c_uint16, 16),
    ]
...

$ python sample.py
bytes abef3412
size 4
```

and I get the same result if I change everything to `c_uint32`:

```
class Version(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('n1', c_uint32, 8),
        ('n2', c_uint32, 8),
        ('n3', c_uint32, 16),
    ]
...

$ python sample.py
bytes abef3412
size 4
```

#### Questions

1. If Ctypes uses natively the c library, why I am getting different results?
2. Why in the first python snippet I get one extra byte? I could somehow understand if it would be multiple of 4, but why 5 bytes?
3. Why the last two versions of the struct definitions in python seem to be compatible with what C does?

#### Update

I opened an issue https://bugs.python.org/issue41932 since looks like it is a bug, will continue updating this post with any updates.

Comment: This issue seems to be related to https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/19850 but without the pragmas. I will also try to follow up there.

Answer (score 0):

Hm.

Here (https://docs.python.org/2.5/lib/ctypes-bit-fields-in-structures-unions.html) it says that

> Bit fields are only possible for integer fields, the bit width is specified as the third item in the *fields* tuples:

So perhaps you have to use type `c_int` for bitfields?

It appears that the sizeof here might be passing the struct by value, which is not supported by ctypes.

https://github.com/beeware/rubicon-objc/pull/157

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.

The doc says integer fields, and to my POV does not say explicitly *c_int*, so any other type is still ok-ish. Now, if I use *c_int* it works and it would be the same as in my third case (where I used *c_int32*) since *c_int32* could be an alias for *c_int* depending on the platform.

``
class ctypes.c_int32
    Represents the C 32-bit signed int datatype. Usually an alias for c_int.
``